# How to set focus for next tab in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[**Example File Link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhRHkJZZyczMKI00A5aJ?p=preview)

```
Hi all,
```

Here I created sample for tabs. What I exactly need is, in this sample i am doing validation with entering anything click submit the focus will go to invalid text which is working fine but once tab one fully valid that time it need to switch to second and set focus is not working how to achieve this can anyone help me on this...

For Ref:-
Without fill anything working fine

[image: Working Fine]

After fill every click submit it need to jump and check validation..
[image: fails]

something like this

[image]

Comment: how do you set tab as active ?

Comment: $scope.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        }

Comment: Because of that one Am also struggle. I don't know How to set tab as active without click(manually by coding)..

Comment: you can use watch just keep a watch on variable and call method on valid

Comment: can u give me some runable sample @ ngLover

Comment: create a plunkr then only can help and i dont have any sample

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EhRHkJZZyczMKI00A5aJ?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103712/discussion-between-nglover-and-suresh-b).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem have a look at this , i have used broadcast method to a call method from controller to directive but it can be varied we can also use different approach to call directives method from controller. so that we can change active tab.

[Here is the working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0SxywqZnF02yyFqtseF9?p=preview)

**JS file**

```
angular.module('components', []).
  directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        paneNum : '='
      },
      controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
        var panes = $scope.panes = [];
        $scope.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        }

        $scope.$on('changeText',function(event, data){
          var j = 0;
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            j++
            pane.selected = false;
            if(j==data.id)
            {
               pane.selected = true;
            }
          });
         });

        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
          panes.push(pane);
        }
      }],
      template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
          '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
              '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  }).
  directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      require: '^tabs',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
        tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })
  .controller('sample', function($scope,$rootScope){
     $scope.activeTab = 1;
      $scope.Submit = function(){
        var schema = {
          1:["FirstName","MiddleName","LastName"],
          2:["Contact","Address1","Address2"],
          3:["Phone","Mobile","Mobile1"]

        };
        var valid = true;
        angular.forEach(schema[$scope.activeTab],function(v){
          if(!$scope.myForm[v].$valid)
          {
            valid = false;
          }
        });
        if(valid)
        {
          $scope.activeTab++;
        }
      $rootScope.$broadcast('changeText',{id :$scope.activeTab});

      }


  });
```

**Html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
   <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="components" ng-controller="sample">
  <h3>BootStrap Tab Component</h3>
  <form role="form" ng-controller="sample" name="myForm">
  <tabs>
    <pane id="FirstTab" title="First Tab">
      <div><div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" required ng-model="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="MiddleName" required ng-model="MiddleName" class="form-control" id="MiddleName">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" required ng-model="LastName" class="form-control" id="LastName">
  </div>

  </div>
    </pane>
    <pane id="SecondTab" title="Second Tab">
      <div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Contact</label>
          <input type="text" name="Contact" required ng-model="Contact" class="form-control" id="Contact">
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Address1</label>
          <input type="text" required name="Address1"  ng-model="Address1" class="form-control" id="Address1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Address2</label>
          <input type="text" required name="Address2" ng-model="Address2" class="form-control" id="Address2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </pane>
     <pane id="ThirdTab" title="Third Tab">
      <div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" required name="Phone" ng-model="Phone" class="form-control" id="Phone">
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Mobile</label>
          <input type="text" required name="Mobile" ng-model="Mobile" class="form-control" id="Mobile">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Mobile1</label>
          <input type="text" required  name="Mobile1"  ng-model="Mobile1" class="form-control" id="Mobile1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </pane>
     <pane id="FourthTab" title="Fourth Tab">
      <div>This is the content of the Fourth tab.</div>
    </pane>
  </tabs>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Submit()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Really done great job. is it possible to create schema dynamically and to create angular.forEach function inside directive why because its not possible to do same in every controller..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/0SxywqZnF02yyFqtseF9?p=preview Made some changes have a look just create schema in your controller

Comment: previous one is proper way.why because every page will not contain tab. i thing need create directive for submit @ngLover

Comment: can we chat?   @ng lover